# gVim's .vimrc is not honoring conditional statement

Tags: vim

I have gVim 8.0.69 installed on my Windows 10 system along with Cygwin. I'm using the same .vimrc for both to keep them in sync. Some settings don't apply to both, so I'm using some conditional expressions in my .vimrc to selectively apply settings:

```
if !(has("gui_running"))
  if version >= 747
    " line 199 is the next line
    set listchars=eol:-|,tab:>_,trail:~,extends:>,precedes:<,space:_ 
  else 
    set listchars=eol:-|,tab:>_,trail:~,extends:>,precedes:<,
  endif
endif
```

gVim is reporting the following error when I start it:

```
Error detected while processing C:\Users\<user name>\.vimrc:
line  199:
E488: Trailing characters: ,tab:>_,trail:~,extends:>,precedes:<,space:_
```

The line number refers to the first `set listchars` command.

Executing `:echo !(has("gui_running"))` in the gVim window reports `0`, and `:echo has("gui_running")` returns `1`, so I know the conditional is evaluating correctly after the program has started

Why is this line even being executed?

Comment: @melpomene Put that in an answer and I'll accept it. The `|` was the problem. Your note about gVim scanning for the `endif` explains why that line was parsed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know for sure, but vim still has to scan the commands to find the corresponding `else` or `endif`.

You have a `|` in there; `|` is a command separator. You could have written

```
if ...
    set foo=bar|endif
```

so vim has to look at the part after the pipe to see what command it is.

I think you need to escape the pipe with `set listchars=eol:-\|,tab:>_,...`.

Comment: The `|` was indeed the problem, but escaping it doesn't help. I've just replaced it with `eol=~` and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 4):

The problem doesn't come only from the `|` character but it comes mainly from the number of characters entered to the string setting `eol`.

From `:help listchars` it says:

```sh
                        *lcs-eol*
  eol:c Character to show at the end of each line.  When
        omitted, there is no extra character at the end
```

It means that `eol` **at most** needs **1 single character** but you gave it two : `-` and `|`.

If you still want to list `eol` by `|` you need to **escape it** so it will not be interpreted as a pipe.

The exact `set` cmd would be in that case:

```
set listchars=eol:\|,tab:>_,trail:~,extends:>,precedes:<,space:_
```